# Modifying docstring slot of an existing Emacs Lisp function

Tags: emacs, docstring

For various reasons I've been forced to use Emacs git master for development. In this version I'm regularly getting lots of warnings in the form

```
No docstring slot for tags-lazy-completion-table
No docstring slot for etags--xref-backend
No docstring slot for gnus-intersection
No docstring slot for grep-compute-defaults
...
```

which often are so many that it slows down my interaction. Is it possible to set the docstring of a an already defined Emacs Lisp function without modifying its existing body definition?

Comment: Why would a missing doc-string slow down your workflow?  I never have an occasion to query/see a doc-string unless I open a `*Help*` buffer relating to that function/variable/macro; or, unless I visit the source code manually.  If this is a bug in the `master`, then it may behoove you to submit a bug report to the Emacs development team:  bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.  Perhaps you have something custom/special running all the time that looks for doc-strings in functions that are being called ...?  If so, then maybe that custom/special thing is what needs to be fixed.

Comment: This happens on Git master only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stefan has addressed your actual problem, but to answer the stated question:

> Is it possible to set the docstring of a an already defined Emacs
>   Lisp function without modifying its existing body definition?

Yes, you can, via the `function-documentation` symbol property.

```
(put FUNCTIONSYMBOL 'function-documentation VALUE)
```

In most cases VALUE would be a string.

See:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Documentation Basics`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Accessing Documentation`

Answer (score 3):

The `No docstring slot for ...` warnings are your problem, not the absence of docstrings (which is copmpletely normal).  I suggest you try

```
(setq debug-on-message "\\`No docstring slot for")
```

and then look at the backtrace you'll (hopefully) get to try and figure out which packages emits this warning and why (and especially why it only does so in Emacs-master: might be a bug in Emacs-master, or an incompatibility ... in either case Emacs maintainers may want to hear about it).